# Spring batch: effectively relating header and body records

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I'm trying to write a proof of concept with Spring Batch that involves reading a fixed-width file and inserting records into a database. I have zero experience to fall back on and am finding the documentation a little light on what I want to achieve.

I can read the header line and body lines no problem (using `FixedLengthTokenizer` and `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper`). However, when it comes to building the domain objects, I need to do two things which are less obvious:

- The object storing the header ID, filename etc also needs the total number of records in the file (not the number written to DB - this is to facilitate manual checks if needed)
- The object storing the individual records needs to reference the header ID of the file

In other words, item-by-item reading, processing and writing isn't enough. The data corresponding to each row depends on other rows in the file.

I'm sure there must be a clean Spring-based approach, I'm just not sure where to start looking.

Example:

```
HDR 12345
ROW 2013-08-01 Lorem ipsum
ROW 2013-08-01 dolor sit amet
```

The three domain objects I need to build are:

```
Header {id: 12345, records: 2}
Record {header_id: 12345, text: Lorem ipsum }
Record {header_id: 12345, text: dolor sit amet }
```

In production the files would be significantly more complex and very large - it wouldn't be ideal to write them out in an intermediate state, for instance, although I wonder if the solution might involve processing them in two passes, somehow building the required data that way?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In spring-batch examples there is a sample called 'multilineOrderJob': it compose single domain object from multiline file. Take a look.

Comment: You can also read the header and store it in the ExecutionContext, then refer to it later.